# Printing binary search tree, segmentation fault error 11

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

could you help me?

Program reads words from a file and puts them into binary search tree, but I get "Segmentation fault: 11" when running my print function.

```
struct node {
    char * item;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
};

struct node * new(char * a) {
    struct node * new;
    new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    new->item = a;
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    return new;
}

struct node * insert(struct node * a, char * b) {
    if(a == NULL) {
        a = new(b);
    }
    else if (b <= a->item) {
        a->left = insert(a->left, b);
    }
    else {
        a->right = insert(a->right, b);
    }
    return a;
}

void print(struct node * a) {
    if (a->left == NULL && a->right == NULL)
        printf("%s", a->item);
    else if (a->left != NULL)
        print(a->left);
    else
        print(a->right);
}
```

from main.c :

```
   struct node * root = NULL;
   struct node * start;

   start = root;

   while (fscanf(fp, "%s", temp) != EOF) {
   root = insert(root, temp); // insert function works ok
   }

   print(start);
```

UPDATE:
I've made a change in main.c:

```
int i = 0;

while (fscanf(fp, "%s", temp) != EOF) {
        root = insert(root, temp);
        if (!i) {
            start = root;
            i = 1;
        }
    }
```

Now it doesn't show error, but it prints only the last word from the tree instead of printing it recursively. Any suggestions?

UPDATE #2:
Thank you for your help. Following your suggestions I've made changes to this function:

```
struct node * new(char * a) {
    struct node * new;
    char * stringcopy;
    stringcopy = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);
    strcpy(stringcopy, a);
    new = malloc(sizeof(* new));
    new->item = stringcopy;
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

Now everything works fine.

Comment: are you by any chance naming `print` function incorrectly as `printplease` or is it a different function? Plus you don't need to use so many `if-else` as only one is needed. IMPORTANT: Please provide the entire code.

Comment: You assign `root` to `start` right at the beginning.  At that point both `root` and `start` are `NULL`.  You then update `root`, but you never change `start`, so `start` remains `NULL`.  You then try to print `start`, i.e. `NULL`.  So you get a seg fault.

Comment: @Observer Sorry, it's the same function, wanted to make shorter name for this post and forgotten to change all instances. I wanted to post entire code, but it was too long and I couldn't post it.

Comment: @TomKarzes, thanks, that could be the problem, I will check it in a moment

Comment: `new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));` **-->>** `new = malloc(sizeof *new);`

Comment: And, instead of storing the pointer passed as argument, you should  make a **copy** of the string: `new->item = a;` **-->>** `new->item = strdup(a);`

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was almost certainly that `start` was `NULL` since you did not update it when you updated `root`. (Meanwhile it seems that the whole `start` is unnecessary; just use `root` directly.)

The new problem (printing only the last word) is that you are not traversing the tree correctly: your `print` function only prints if both `left` and `right` are `NULL`, so only a leaf node is ever printed, and furthermore it does not descend into the `right` branch if there is a `left` branch.

You could try something like this instead (untested code):

```
void print(struct node * a) {
    if (a == NULL) { return; }
    print(a->left);
    (void) puts(a->item);
    print(a->right);
}
```

In particular, note that if you are at a non-`NULL` node, you need to print its `item` unconditionally, or the complete output will be missing that node.

Another problem *seems to be* that you are not copying `item` when you create the node. So if your `temp` in `insert(root, temp)` is indeed a temporary object that will be overwritten or freed, all of your `item`s (except possibly the last) will be invalid by the time you try to print them. Instead of assigning `new->item = a`, do the equivalent of `new->item = strdup(a)` and then remember to `free` it when you free the node.

(`strdup` is not in the C standard library, but it is easy to implement: allocate enough space for the string, including NUL terminator, and copy.)

Also, the comparison `b <= a->item` is almost certainly not doing what you expect it to; see `strcmp`.

Comment: Stylistic notes not directly related to the problems: don't cast the return value of `malloc`, prefer `sizeof(*pointer)` over `sizeof(struct value_pointed_to)`, use `{ }` around the then/else branches of `if`, consider more sensible names for your variables than `a` and `b` (e.g., `node`, `item`).

Comment: @M.Chelm: (re. a deleted comment) `sizeof char` == 1 (by definition), so `malloc(strlen(a) + 1)` suffices.